# How to make tappable UIImages that run functions?(Swift)

Tags: swift, uiimageview, clickable

(I just started using Swift a few days ago and am relatively new to programming, so please bear with me.) I am trying to make random blocks appear on the screen, and the user must tap them to make them disappear. I have been able to create the blocks, but I have no idea how to actually make them tappable. Can someone please help me? This is my code so far:

```
func createBlock(){

    let imageName = "block.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: -50, width: size, height: size)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {

        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.xPosition, y: 590, width: self.size, height: self.size)

        }, completion: { animationFinished in


            imageView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.life-=1


    })



}
```

I want to make the block disappear when tapped; any suggestions on how I can do that?

Comment: You should really look into SpriteKit. Recognizing taps on images is easy, but doing that while they are being animated not so much. SpriteKit is a simple 2d game engine that was built for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely simple to do, just use a UITapGestureRecognizer. I typically initialize the recognizer as a global variable.

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
```

Then in your viewDidLoad:

```
// Replace with your function
tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "removeBlock")
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still isn't working :( I have the "removeBlock" function in the createBlock function, so maybe that's why it isn't working? And should I add the "tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "removeBlock")
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)" code INSIDE the createBlock function?

Answer (score 0):

```
func removeImage(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    gesture.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}

func createBlock() {
    let imageName = "block.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: -50, width: size, height: size)

    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true                       // IMPORTANT
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "removeImage:"))

    self.view.addSubview(imageView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: options, animations: {

        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.xPosition, y: 590, width: self.size, height: self.size)

    }, { _ in
        imageView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.life-=1
    })
}
```

Notice `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true` it is really important because that will allow touch events on that view, it is set to false as defaul in UIImgageView.

Comment: Thank you @Arbitur , but it still didn't work...When I tap the blocks, nothing happens....

Comment: Works for me, but I tested when removing the UIView animation. If you're trying to remove it while its animating this is the wrong approach because tap events doesnt work while animating.

Comment: I tink I know now what you're doing :) you're making a game and the "blocks" are some sort of enemy and if you dont tap them before they ... something you lose a life. Then this is definitely the wrong approach for you.

Comment: yes, thats what I want to do, but it's just not working out! You said this is the wrong approach, what do u recomend?

Comment: I dont know for sure the best solution but using an NSTimer to update UI works with tap events, but its harder to program. Otherwise maybe SpriteKit has something that you might want to use, take a look at it.

Comment: Or maybe using only CALayers and CAAnimations and using hitTest() will work. I havent tested so I dont know for sure.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I can probably just create an NSTimer that updates the block's Y value instead of an animation so the touches can be detected, right? I will also look into CALayers and CAAnimations :) @Arbitur